# Given a managed reference to a struct, how to obtain a managed reference to a field at offset?

Tags: c#, return-by-reference, c#-8.0

I am trying to implement fixed size arrays in C#, that are parametrized by hacky type-level numerics. See [GitHub](https://github.com/losttech/TypeNum/)

I want to implement a method, that would work like this:

```
static ref T Ref(this ref TContainer container, int index)
  where T: unmanaged
  where TContainer: unmanaged
  => ref container[index];
```

Now the problem is: I know, that `TContainer` internally consists of N fields of type `T`. But it does not actually implement the indexing operation (or any interface whatsoever).

What I can do is:

```
CheckIndex(index);
fixed (TContainer* self = &container) {
    T* data = (T*)self;
    return ref data[index];
}
```

This compiles with `unsafe`, but I have two questions:

1. Will the lifetime of the managed reference retrieved like this be tracked properly?
2. Does use of `fixed` in this context have any performance cost? (e.g. GC pinning, aliasing issues, etc)

Additionally, the example with `fixed` and `return ref` from above also compiles even when I replace the parameter type `ref TContainer` with just `TContainer`, or, which should be the same, just declare it as an instance member instead of an extension method. It even works in a sample test case, but I can't see why it does, because under normal circumstances one can't return `ref this.field` from a struct instance method.

Comment: *fixed* doesn't have a bug, it is extremely cheap because it doesn't actually require pinning.  The variable has the [pinned] attribute, if the GC happens to collect just as this code is executing then it finds [pinned] back and knows not to move the object.  It is actually ref data[] that can be painful.  Generates an interior pointer inside the object, the GC has to plod through the entire heap segment to find the object back.  That cost is hard to measure since it only drives up the "% of time in GC" overhead and you'd have to be unlucky that the GC runs while it is live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. yes, because you reconstruct the unmanaged pointer back into a managed pointer while it is pinned; at no point can the managed pointer be invalid
2. no, `fixed` uses a very-low overhead mechanism - basically, `fixed` just marks a local variable as having special meaning; when the GC runs, it is *already* walking the stack-frames, and when it does so it looks for these locals and notes that the value of them should be considered pinned

However! It sounds like the concept you're really after here is `Span<T>` (or `Memory<T>`) - a `Span<T>` is basically a "range" using managed pointers.

Here's a version that doesn't use `unsafe`:

```
public static ref T Ref<T, TContainer>(this ref TContainer container, int index)
    where TContainer : unmanaged
    where T : unmanaged
{
    if (index < 0 || Unsafe.SizeOf<T>() * (index + 1) > Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>())
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
    ref T first = ref Unsafe.As<TContainer, T>(ref container);
    return ref Unsafe.Add<T>(ref first, index);
}
```

Note that it is still "unsafe", though.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, `Unsafe` here is [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)

Comment: Additional side note: in terms of terminology, this is "obtaining an interior-pointer of value-type `T` from a managed reference of value-type `TContainer`"

Comment: What's the harm of using `unsafe` vs the `Unsafe` class?

Comment: Also I am not sure what does your quoted unsafe in the last sentence refers to.

Comment: @Lost many of the methods in Unsafe aren't actually "unsafe" - they just expose things that are possible in IL, but can't be expressed in C#.

Comment: @Lost some things genuinely are "unsafe", of course - even Unsafe.Add - if you add arbitrarily, you can go outside of the defined object - hence the SizeOf checks! But : anything that minimises the "unsafe" in your own code is usually a good thing.